# strange issues with JWplayer 6 and image overlaying video

Tags: javascript, streaming, jwplayer, jwplayer6

We are having an issue with JWplayer, that has bizarrely only just cropped up since changing our licence to the ads version.

for streaming live video this is an example of the playlist that we are passing to the player:

```
"playlist": [{
    "title": "a title",
    "image": "/image.png",
    "sources": [{
        "file": "http://{reacted-CDN-Link}/Playlist.m3u8",
        "width": ""
    }, {
        "file": "ramp://{reacted-CDN-Link}/rtmp-wowza-publish-point",
        "width": ""
    }]
```

What we are finding, is when this is playing live video the player loads, but with the image overlaying the video. (this is primarily when using the HLS stream )

If I remove the image part of the playlist then it works okay. (yes I have updated both the key and the player)

The other strange thing I am finding, is that when the player first loads (whist the live stream is loading) the control bar has the expected elements, such as full screen, level selection (HLS). However when the player starts to play, the control bar has no full screen button, and no DVR (when turned on and configured)

These issues are only happening on Live streams and not on VOD.

Has anyone else come across anything like this?

Comment: Currently there are no Events Live Ethan. ill get something sorted for the next one which I think is Friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an Update, we worked out that it was an error on the configuration of the wowza server. It appeared that it was outputting the m3u8 with audio only. This caused JWPlayer to act as expected, and play back as if there was only an Audio track.